# passing parameters to pig udf could not instantiate with arguments

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-pig, user-defined-functions, udf

I'm trying to write pig UDF that can accept parameters.

I read some blogs and got that It can be done by adding parameterized constructor.

So my code for UDF is :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
public class LeftPad extends EvalFunc<String> {

    String size;
    String padChar;
    public LeftPad(String size, String padChar) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.size = size;
        this.padChar = padChar;
    }

    @Override
    public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        try {
            if (input == null || input.size() == 0)
                return null;
            String str = (String) input.get(0);         
            return StringUtils.leftPad(str, Integer.valueOf(size), padChar).toString();

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Also tried the constructor definition as:

```
public LeftPad(int size, Char padChar)
```

But the read somwhere that it supports String only and changed to above.

Script lines used on grunt console:

```
REGISTER pig_udf4.jar
DEFINE l_pad pig_udf4.LeftPad('12','x');
data = Load myData.csv USING PigStorage(,) as (....);
C = FOREACH data GENERATE l_pad('12','x');
DUMP C;
```

Tried varying the 4th line as

```
C = FOREACH data GENERATE l_pad();
```

but still facing the same issue.

logs :

```
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 1200: could not instantiate 'LeftPad' with arguments '[12, x]'

Failed to parse: could not instantiate 'LeftPad' with arguments '[12, x]'
        at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:201)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.validateQuery(PigServer.java:1791)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1764)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:707)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processPig(GruntParser.java:1075)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:505)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:231)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:206)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:66)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:564)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:176)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate 'LeftPad' with arguments '[12, x]'
        at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.instantiateFuncFromSpec(PigContext.java:759)
        at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.expression.UserFuncExpression.getFieldSchema(UserFuncExpression.java:222)
        at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.FieldSchemaResetter.execute(SchemaResetter.java:264)
        at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.expression.AllSameExpressionVisitor.visit(AllSameExpressionVisitor.java:143)
        at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.expression.UserFuncExpression.accept(UserFuncExpression.java:113)
        at org.apache.pig.newplan.ReverseDependencyOrderWalker.walk(ReverseDependencyOrderWalker.java:70)
        at org.apache.pig.newplan.PlanVisitor.visit(PlanVisitor.java:52)
        at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.SchemaResetter.visitAll(SchemaResetter.java:67)
        at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.SchemaResetter.visit(SchemaResetter.java:122)
        at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.relational.LOGenerate.accept(LOGenerate.java:245)
        at org.apache.pig.newplan.DependencyOrderWalker.walk(DependencyOrderWalker.java:75)
        at org.apache.pig.newplan.logical.optimizer.SchemaResetter.visit(SchemaResetter.java:114)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildForeachOp(LogicalPlanBuilder.java:1055)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.foreach_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:15896)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.op_clause(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1933)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.general_statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:1102)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.statement(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:560)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.query(LogicalPlanGenerator.java:421)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:191)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: LeftPad.<init>([Ljava.lang.String;)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825)
        at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.instantiateFuncFromSpec(PigContext.java:746)
        ... 34 more
================================================================================
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> NoSuchMethodException: LeftPad.([Ljava.lang.String;)

You gave a String Array, not two Strings.

Add another consructor

```
public LeftPad(String... args) {
    this(args[0], args[1]);
}
```

Besides that, I doubt you need `DEFINE`.

Your parameters are passed into the input Tuple, so you get the size and character from that

Comment: added the constructor as said, Now the log says - `ERROR 1070: Could not resolve pig_udf4.LeftPad using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]

Failed to parse: Pig script failed to parse:
<line 3, column 36> Failed to generate logical plan. Nested exception: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 1070          : Could not resolve pig_udf4.LeftPad using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]` tried ` C = FOREACH panasonic_data GENERATE l_pad('12','x');` & `l_pad()` too

Comment: That error would indicate that you didn't register the jar and UDF correctly

Comment: I haven't faced any issue in Registering & Defining though as stated the statements in the question. Now, I will try for the alternatives of Registering & Defining Jar.

Comment: I think you just need to use the exec function correctly

Comment: What worked for me is making jar of the class itself. may be because i have made all udfs in default package and hence don't specify fully qualified package name while defining the class & registering the jar.

Comment: You had `pig_udf4.LeftPad`, so yes, if you had no `package pig_udf4` statement in your code, then that would be the reason. You can have many UDF's in that one JAR